# Single power supply replacement for LM741 op amp?

Tags: analog

I'm trying to build a twin-T oscillator for synthesising drum sounds. The LM741 heats up pretty quickly and the circuit hardly oscillates even when the feedback is at 100 per cent. Even with an LM386 amp I hardly get anything (though I can see some oscillation on the scope). The circuit gets 10ms 5V pulses from an Arduino. Does the TL071/2 run from single supply? Can it replace the LM741?

[image: Schematic_http://www.flickr.com/photos/alkopop79/8644385451/]

Comment: 1. Any op amp can run from a single supply.
2. It is difficult to tell what is actually being asked here. Please post a schematic.

Comment: Schematics here:  http://www.flickr.com/photos/alkopop79/8644385451/

Comment: I suspect a capacitor in series with the output would improve behaviour - at the moment it's effectively DC-coupled the output to ground.

Comment: What is the power supply voltage being used?

Comment: https://www.circuitlab.com/browse/by-tag/drum/  
Your output loads your (-) feedback loop.

Comment: The power supply is 9V. I suspect the lack of virtual ground won't help the 741.

Comment: Optionparty, the feedback is necessary to create oscillation. Further simulation revealed that the circuit won't work (i.e. won't oscillate) without virtual ground. I guess I need to build a rail splitter. Still, are there op amps that do not need virtual ground?

Comment: Here's a link of the circuit [click here](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/g52648/twin-t-with-trigger/) , feel free to simulate it (Open in editor.

Comment: @alkopop79 Keep in mind that the LM386 is _not_ an operational amplifier - it's a small audio power amp.  It generally won't work in standard op-amp circuits as a "drop in" replacement without modification of the ciruit.

Answer (score 1):

It's working now. I replaced the 741 for a TL072 and a resistor had to be replaced for a larger one (the 2.2M). As for the split rail, I made a simple rail splitter that converts 9V to 4.5V, 0V and -4.5V.

Comment: The circuit here: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/g52648/screenshot/1024x768/

Comment: You could also checkout LM324

Comment: A rail splitters does not convert 9V to +/- 4.5. That's a misleading way to look at it. Your circuit is powered on 9V. Ground is at 0V.  What the splitter circuit does is provides a bias voltage reference. That reference isn't a real ground. It cannot sink current like a real ground.  You should not use the ground symbol for that node.